# Why react need to include react.js after using webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

See the [doc of react](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/package-management.html#using-react-from-npm)

It has an main.js:

```
// main.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

After bundled with webpack, it gave out an html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <!-- No need for Babel! -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script src="build/helloworld.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

According to the doc, react is already required in helloworld.js, why it source it again here?

Comment: After what was bundled with webpack? It's hard to know what your particular build is doing without any details.

Comment: @DaveNewton It's in the doc link, but anyway, I paste the main.js here.

Comment: What makes you think it will be in the `helloworld.js` file?

Comment: that depends on how you configured webpack. You can configure it to bundle react with your files or to use a globally available React object, that would be added to page.

Comment: The docs you sent is saying that you can use React with webpack, but it's not showing the config for webpack.

Comment: I follow the doc exactly, and it's included in bundled js, I think some part of the doc is inappropriate.